# Representing ''Class " construct in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am implementing a llvm transformation pass. And while inserting a function call, I need to pass custom 'class' object as an argument.
I have a Thread object that I need to pass as an argument: the function signature as follows:

```
    void MyThread::initialize(int num ,MyThread* myThread)
```

and through my pass , I need to add the following instruction:

```
    myThread->initialize(Count, myThread);
```

I don't know how to represent the myThread object's type while preparing it as an argument. For example, if it is an integer we know how to get the type but in our case how to represent class construct as a type?

Answer (score 0):

Classes are normally represented as structs in LLVM IR. You could check what clang does, certainly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.To clarify further , i am trying to use following method:: CallInst::Create(hook,args)->insertAfter(i) . Here the args should be arrayref of llvm::Value *. Can u help me how to get myClass as Structtype and pass it as Value pointer ?